# Error deploying war on tomcat9 via maven - Windows

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Any help would be appreciated, as this config works on mac but not on a windows machine.

My command:
mvn clean install && mvn tomcat7:redeploy

Error message:

```
--- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) @ web-customer-tracker ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/web-customer-tracker
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fweb-customer-tracker&update=true
2692/20011 KB
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fweb-customer-tracker&update=true
2692/20011 KB
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fweb-customer-tracker&update=true
2884/20011 KB
[INFO] I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[INFO] Retrying request
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=%2Fweb-customer-tracker&update=true
2884/20011 KB
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.686 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-14T21:19:25+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:redeploy (default-cli) on project web-customer-tracker: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset by peer: socket write error -> [Help 1]
```

Tomcat is running on port 8080

pom.xml

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/web-customer-tracker</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>web-customer-tracker</finalName>
    </build>
```

~/.m2/settings.xml

```
<server>
    <id>TomcatServer</id>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>password</password>
</server>
```

tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Tomcat: 9.0.10
Maven: 3.3.4
JDK: java version "1.8.0_172"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having tried almost everything, I deleted my settings.xml in m2. Then I made the following change in my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>TomcatServer</server>
                <username>admin</username>
                <password>password</password>
                <path>/web-customer-tracker</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>web-customer-tracker</finalName>
</build>
```

I added the username & password from settings.xml to the pom file, and it worked. Please not this issue does not happen on a UNIX based system.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the error
Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Run as Administrator start two separate command prompt terminals.
In the first terminal, go to your tomcat bin dir & run shutdown.bat & thereafter startup.bat in my case 
c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\bin>shutdown.bat
c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-8.5.8\bin>startup.bat

In the second terminal, go to your maven webapp dir then run the mvn command. In my case
mvn tomcat7:deploy

It will be a BUILD SUCCESS!!!